# Merging Duplicate records on Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following table which gets incremental updates. I need to write a normal Hive query to merge the rows with the same key value with most recent values.

```
Key |  A  |  B  |   C  |  Timestamp
K1  |  X  |  Null |  Null | 2015-05-03
K1 |  Null | Y  |    Z  |  2015-05-02
K1  |  Foo |  Bar  |  Baz  | 2015-05-01
```

Want to get:

```
Key |  A  |  B  |   C  |  Timestamp
K1  | X  | Y  |  Z  |  2015-05-03
```

Comment: First thought - coalesce, but I don't think that's correct

Comment: if column are less you can try as hive does not support CTE call again to create new CTE you have to create a new table or in trim storage .then i have some soln..

Answer (score 0):

Use first_value() function to get last not null value. Need to concat sort keys because last_value works only with one sort key.

Demo:

```
select distinct
key,
first_value(A) over (partition by Key order by concat(case when A is null then '1' else '2' end,'_',Timestamp)desc) A,
first_value(B) over (partition by Key order by concat(case when B is null then '1' else '2' end,'_',Timestamp)desc) B,
first_value(C) over (partition by Key order by concat(case when C is null then '1' else '2' end,'_',Timestamp)desc) C,
max(timestamp) over(partition by key) timestamp
from 
(  ---------Replace this subquery with your table
select 'K1'  key,  'X'   a, Null    b,  Null   c, '2015-05-03' timestamp union all 
select 'K1'  key,  null  a, 'Y'     b,  'Z'    c, '2015-05-02' timestamp union all
select 'K1'  key,  'Foo' a, 'Bar'   b,  'Baz'  c, '2015-05-01' timestamp
)s
;
```

Output:

```
OK
key     a       b       c       timestamp
K1      X       Y       Z       2015-05-03
```